# Jenkins or Hudson Build Options and/or packaging operations

Tags: hudson, package, jenkins

I have a very large project I wish to put under Jenkin's (or Hudson's) care. Thing is, we have a lot of subprojects that are to be included at a very specific place in the main project (as plugins). I'd like to facilitate the life of my product team by permitting them to select which plugins should be included in their package.

Now I don't know if it's under Jenkin's (or Hudson's) jurisdiction to do such a thing or if I should address my needs elsewhere, but elsewhere is a good answer too, provided that I'm shown where I need to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you are packaging those plugins, you can add variables to your Jenkins job and then write a custom command shells that adds the plugins based on the variable values.

Update:  If you go to Configure (or Add) Job, then `Build Environment -> Configure release build`, you'll see an option to `Add Parameter`.  One of the choices is a Boolean, which is represented as a checkbox.

Comment: Can I somehow wire those variables to checkboxes?

Comment: This is the awesomest thing ever, right next to bacon. Thanks.